# Html page session management using htmlunit library

Tags: java, rest, html-parsing, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit for parsing html page in java. The site i want to parse has an authentication step. I login to the website using username and password then do some searching. I have been successfully automated the login system do other things on that website as i need. I built a rest api where user call that api by a string parameter, web service  then do the login and return an image. What i want is keep the loggedin home page so when another user calls that api web service doesn’t need to do the login as long as the session of homepage remains. How can I achieve this in java using htmlunit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HtmlUnit Session Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005349/htmlunit-session-management)

Comment: if i create webclient with cookie enabled and login to site, then will another request to that api have the same instance of webclient ?